# Why is the projection onto the symmetric subspace separable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hilbert-space, mathematics

Let $L$ be the symmetric subspace of $(\mathbb{C}^d)^{\otimes n}$. In other words $\left| \psi \right\rangle \in L$ iff $\left| \psi \right\rangle$ is permutation-invariant. I want to know why the projection $\Pi$ onto $L$ is separable.

For $d=n=2$ I know $\Pi$ is separable by the positive partial transpose criterion. But how about other $d,n$?

Comment: Take two spin-1/2 particles.  The S=1 subspace is symmetric but the M=0 state in this subspace is not separable.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero. Sorry. $\Pi = \left| 00 \right\rangle\left\langle 00 \right| +  \left| 11 \right\rangle\left\langle 11 \right| + 1/2  (\left| 01 \right\rangle +\left| 10 \right\rangle )(\left\langle 01 \right|+\left\langle 10 \right|)$ in your example. But it is indeed separable.

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand your question.  Separable usually means separable in terms of the first and second particle.  $\vert 01\rangle +\vert 10\rangle=\vert 0\rangle\vert 1\rangle+\vert 1\rangle\vert 0\rangle$ is clearly not separable because not of the form $\vert a\rangle\vert b\rangle$.  Why apply any kind of partial transpose criteria to a projection operator?

Comment: Yeah sorry I messed up my comment.  Still don’t understand your question as to why you want to talk about seperability of a projection operator.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero. Mathematically, a quantum state is just an operator. By normalization, $\Pi/3$ is a legit quantum state. So we can ask why $\Pi/3$ is a separable state if you don't feel quite comfortable of my original question.

Comment: @user193108 This seems very related to the quantum de Finetti theorem

Comment: @glS Could you please give more hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Schur-Weyl duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Weyl_duality) asserts that $(\mathbb C^d)^{\otimes N}$ can be decomposed into a direct sum 
$$
\bigoplus_n P_n \otimes R_n
$$
on which the permutation group of the $N$ copies and $\mathrm{U}(d)$ act irreducibly, respectively.  In particular, if we start with a fully symmetric state 
$$
|\psi\rangle = \otimes^N|\phi\rangle
$$
and consider 
\begin{equation}
\label{eq}
\Pi=\int \mathrm{d}U U^{\otimes N}|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|(U^\dagger)^{\otimes N}\ ,
\tag{1}
\end{equation} 
Schur's Lemma tells us that $\Pi$ is the projector onto the fully symmetric space (as we start from a symmetric state and $U^{\otimes N}$ acts irreducibly on it). Thus, Eq. (1) gives us a separable decomposition of $\Pi$, and thus, $\Pi$ is a separable state (up to normalization).

Comment: Thanks. There seems a typo. $(\mathbb{C}^d)^{\otimes n}=\bigoplus_n P_n\otimes R_n$. BTW, can we say something about the separability of  an operator that is sufficiently close to $\Pi$? Say, if we perturbate $\Pi$ by a Hermitian operator $\epsilon$.

Comment: @user193108 Which typo?

Comment: The decompostion of $(\mathbb{C}^d)^{\otimes n}$ should be a direct sum of tensor products.